# VS Code Extension Host is running an old version of Node.js

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When VSCode tries to start one of my extensions ([Salesforce Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode)), the extension crashes. When I check out the console, it looks like the first error, which I'm assuming is the cause of the others and the crash is from the Extension Host saying:

> Unsupported Node.js version 4.2.6, version 8.4.0 of later is required.

I can't even find node version 4.2.6 installed on my machine and my default is 8.12.0. Is the Extension host using a different path than it would use in a terminal? And if so is there some place I should look to find where that path is set? I can't seem to find any information on where it is or how to control what version of Node it's using.

I've tried everything I can think of, including a full uninstall of VSCode and all extensions and deleting the config in .config/Code and .vscode/ and reinstalling it, but it keep getting the same error. This is on Linux Mint v18.3 if that makes a difference. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my own question. It seems it might be the result of installing nvm to manage/install versions of node. The extension host doesn't seem to be using nvm. So, it was just executing the basic version on my machine, which seems to be 4.2.6. I logged in as root and manually updated the nodejs version and everything works fine, now.